# Enable horizontal scroll for TextEdit in Yosemite (Mac OS X 10.10.2)

Tags: macos, textedit

Is enabling horizontal scroll for TextEdit (for Mac OS X 10.10.2) possible?

After going to Preferences and checking or unchecking the box labeled "Wrap to page", the text still wraps to the next line once it reaches the end of the TextEdit window.

Wasn't horizontal scrolling possible in previous versions of Mac OS X? I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.

Comment: I think you must be remembering some other text editor.

Answer (score 1):

TextEdit doesn't work based on a page format. Since it doesn't know how wide your page is, it can't know when to wrap. You'll have to rely on something like Pages if you want to create a document based on a specific page format.

Answer (score 0):

In TextEdit, the "opposite" of 'Wrap to Page' is Wrap to Window'

It's never done text that extends beyond the visible area, left to right -
for that you need something like [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/), or its freeware little brother [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

Comment: Apart from coding (programming)

Comment: @JuanRocamonde - I don't understand your comment. What's apart from coding?

Comment: In programming (coding, makings apps) which can be done with any text editor,  text is formatted in only one horizontal line per paragraph

Comment: Basically the apps you list there are for coding

Comment: Which really doesn't have anything to do with either the question or answer… ;)

Comment: I know, it was just a comment